# Slow Image serving (Windows7 Home + Atom CPU)

Tags: iis, performance, intel-atom

I am in the process of rolling out a touchscreen display system that uses Win 7 Home, IIS, SQL 2K8R2 Express all running on an Intel Atom platform.

I am finding that images (served straight from disk , or resized via aspx) are slow to load, we have beefed up or test atom with 2GB ram and a half decent SSD, but its still no where near as snappy as I'd like.

When I run the same code on a standard desktop PC running the same software it flys, is there some trick to making atoms serve up data nice and fast as people are using them as NAS boxes, so throughput can't be an issue for them.

or am I going to be looking at moving away from the atom platform (would be a shame as the nettops fit our stands nicely.)

Comment: If you open the images directly (i.e. not through IIS) do they open reasonably quickly? Which Atom processor are you using?

Comment: opening the images in picture viewer is nice and snappy, the CPU is the D525 (pineview), the machine itself is a Nettop nT535

Comment: Just to be clear, is the same box being used to access the site? Do you have any special firewalls or anything installed?

Comment: The site is hosted on localhost, firewalls are off, we have installed the loopback adapter to see if that improves things but its still slow with images.

Comment: Do you have anti-virus software installed and if so then have you tried temporarily disabling it?

Comment: no Av on these boxes at this stage.

Comment: Which browser are you are using and have you tried any others? I ask because apparently Firefox and some other browsers can sometimes have problems if IPv6 is enabled: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/06/17/fixing-firefox-slowness-with-localhost-on-vista.aspx and I'm not sure if it has been fixed.

Comment: it runs at the same speed in IE and firefox. (FF version is 3.6.16)

IPv6 is disabled on all adapters as well.